# How to play audio and pause it and then resume it on screen change?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to play a background music from assets when I launch Flutter app and need to pause that when a particular screen arrives. Whenever the user moves from that page it should resume. I tried with audiocache. But I can't pause that. Is there any way I can achieve that? I'm tried with this whenever pause string arrives its stops..but I'm getting error..is there any another way guys??

```
Future<void> playSound(data) async {​​​​​  print("ypooo");  
AudioCache cache = AudioCache()  ;  
AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer()  ;  
if (data == "pause") {​​​​​    print(player);  
  player?.stop();  
}​​​​​ else {​​​​​ 
   cache.play("bg_cover.mp3");
  }​​​​​
}​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a util class for playing the music and pausing it on demand. You can modify it as per your demand.

```
class AudioUtils {
  static AudioCache? _bgAudioCache;
  static AudioPlayer? _bgAudioPlayer;

  static AudioCache? getBGAudioCache() {
    if (_bgAudioCache == null)
      return _bgAudioCache = AudioCache();
    else
      return _bgAudioCache;
  }

  static void playBgMusic() async {
      if (_bgAudioPlayer == null){
        _bgAudioPlayer =
        await getBGAudioCache()?.loop("bg-music.mp3", volume: 0.1);
      } else _resumeBgMusic();
  }

  static void pauseBgMusic() {
    _bgAudioPlayer?.pause();
  }

  static void _resumeBgMusic() {
    _bgAudioPlayer?.resume();
  }

  static disposeBGMusic() {
    _bgAudioPlayer?.dispose();
  }

  static bool isBGMusicPlaying() {
    return _bgAudioPlayer?.state == PlayerState.PLAYING;
  }
}
```